# How to find points on the surface $x^3+y^4-z^3-1=0$ with tangent planes parallel to $xy$ plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to find points on the surface $S:$ $x^3+y^4-z^3-1=0$ with tangent planes parallel to $xy$ plane?

I have calculated  $\nabla S=(3x^2,4y^3,-3z^2)$ but I'm not sure were to go from here if a point were to have a tangent plane parallel to the $xy$ plane then wouldn't the point need to have a normal vector of the form $(0,0,1)$ so we just need to solve $-3z^2=\pm 1$ which has only one solution $z=1/\sqrt 3$?

I know this isn't right though cn anyone explain what I did wrong and what I should've done?

Comment: You need the gradient to have the same direction of $(0,0,1)$, not necessarily equal to it. Hence, you simply need to solve $3x^2=4y^2=0$ and $-3z^2 \neq 0$.

Comment: Oh right because any non-zero multiple will have the same direction. So it would be any point of the form $(0,0,z)~z \ne 0$?

Comment: Exactly. Now you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did wrong was already pointed out by Crostul who shows what you should have done with this first method. Alternatively, you should have done it with another method (differential geometry) :
$$x^3+y^4-z^3-1=0$$
$$3x^2dx+4y^3dy-3z^2dz=0$$
On a tangent plane parallel to $xy$ plane, we have $dz=0$
$$3x^2dx+4y^3dy=0$$
any $dx$ and $dy$ , hense: $3x^2=0$ and $4y^3=0\quad\to\quad 0^3+0^4-z^3-1=0\quad\to\quad z=-1$.

The only convenient point is $(0,0,-1)$

Comment: Oh so once I have found the it will have the form  $(0,0,z)~z \ne 0$ I just sub into surface to find the point on the surface that has this property. Cool!